# Run script before vscode debug with a twist

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to run a script before debugging my python project, but it seems like it gets stuck after the script is done.
If I'm exiting the environment that the script created (Ctrl+d) the debug session is starting, else, it's just stuck there.

I think that it might be happening because the script itself sourcing some files and at the end giving me a new shell.

I'm looking for a way to run a debugger while running the script before the run.

Any ideas?

My launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "preLaunchTask": "Setup"
        }
    ]
```

My tasks.json:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Setup",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "script.csh"
        }
        
    ]
```